# Aggregate on tags regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a way to count the number of tags which exist for documents.

Data looks like following:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("...."),
        "tags": ["active-adult", "active-tradeout"]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("...."),
        "tags": ["active-child", "active-tradeout", "active-junk-tag"]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("...."),
        "tags": ["inactive-adult"]
    }
]
```

This is how I would like the result of the aggregation to look like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "active",
        "total": 2,
        "subtags": {
            "adult": 1,
            "child": 1,
            "tradeout": 2,
            "junk-tag": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "inactive",
        "total": 1,
        "subtags": {
            "adult": 1
        }
    }
]
```

---

I know I can count the tags, but I am looking for regex

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags"},
    {$group: {_id: "$tags", total: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Comment: I wouldnt use regular expressions for embedded structures like stylsheets or xml files. Use an algorithm instead, or at least a GREP program that can run on text in more steps

Comment: Yes that is how I was doing it, but was curious if there was a way to do this via the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little string processing with `$substr` and `$cond` operators to get the desired result (there is no need for regex). This will require MongoDB 2.6+:

```
db.User.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$tags"},
    { $project : { 
        tagType : { 
            $cond : { 
                if : { $eq : [ { $substr : [ "$tags", 0, 6] }, "active" ]}, 
                then: "active", 
                else: "inactive"}
            }, 
        tag: {
            $cond : { 
                if : { $eq : [ { $substr : [ "$tags", 0, 6] }, "active" ]}, 
                then: { $substr : ["$tags", 7, -1]}, 
                else: { $substr : ["$tags", 9, -1]}}
            }
    }},
    { $group : { _id : {tagType : "$tagType", tag: "$tag"} , 
                 total: { $sum: 1}}},
    { $group : { _id : "$_id.tagType", 
                subtags: { $push : {tag : "$_id.tag", total: "$total"}},
                total: { $sum : "$total"}}}
]);
```

The result of this query will be this:

```
{
    "_id" : "inactive",
    "subtags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "adult",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ],
    "total" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : "active",
    "subtags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "junk-tag",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "tag" : "child",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "tag" : "tradeout",
            "total" : 2
        },
        {
            "tag" : "adult",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ],
    "total" : 5
}
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed that the total in the result is counting the total number of tags not the number of documents that had at least one active tag. This query will give you the exact output you wanted, although is slightly more complicated:

```
db.User.aggregate([
    /* unwind so we can process each tag from the array */
    { $unwind : "$tags"},
    /* Remove the active/inactive strings from the tag values 
       and create a new value tagType */
    { $project : { 
        tagType : { 
            $cond : { 
                if : { $eq : [ { $substr : [ "$tags", 0, 6] }, "active" ]}, 
                then: "active", 
                else: "inactive"}
        }, 
        tag: {
            $cond : { 
                if : { $eq : [ { $substr : [ "$tags", 0, 6] }, "active" ]}, 
                then: { $substr : ["$tags", 7, -1]}, 
                else: { $substr : ["$tags", 9, -1]}}
        }
    }},
    /* Group the documents by tag type, so we can 
       find num. of docs by tag type (total) */
    { $group : { _id : "$tagType", 
                 tags :{ $push : "$tag"}, 
                 docId :{ $addToSet : "$_id"}}},
    /* project the values so we can get the 'total' for tag type */
    { $project : { tagType : "$_id", 
                   tags : 1, 
                   "docTotal": { $size : "$docId" }}},
    /* we must unwind to get total count for each tag */
    { $unwind : "$tags"}, 
    /* sum the tags by type and tag value */
    { $group : { _id : {tagType : "$tagType", tag: "$tags"} , 
                 total: { $sum: 1}, docTotal: {$first : "$docTotal"}}},
    /* finally group by tagType so we can get subtags */
    { $group : { _id : "$_id.tagType", 
                 subtags: { $push : {tag : "$_id.tag", total: "$total"}},
                 total: { $first : "$docTotal"}}}
]);
```

Comment: Ahh I see, so it wouldn't be possible to run this on an unknown number of root tags (i.e. 'active', 'active2')? This isn't a condition more a question.

Comment: It should probably be noted that this requires `MongoDB 2.6+`

Comment: > I just noticed that the total in the result is counting the total number of tags not the number of documents 

Actually I was looking for the number of documents with the root-tag and sub-tags.

Comment: @RyanSchumacher this approach was adjusted to fit your example (because I thought you had only two types of tags), but unfortunately it will not work well for the unknown number of tags.

Comment: @RyanSchumacher if you can somehow preprocess the tag names (and maybe add a "category" for each document) when creating a document then you could probably do a simpler aggregation.